# How to code PrepareForSeque in UITableView that has sections and searching

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have constructed a nice TableView that contains sections, searching, and the alphabetical strip on the right.

I tested it and all seemed well until I noticed that anything after the "A"s was not working correctly. I discovered the reason - in my PrepareForSegue I was passing the object I found at the row, but not paying any attention to the sections.

I searched stack overflow and found some things like I am trying to do, but it seems they are coding in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath, no prepare for segue. And I was unable to get any of the code to work.

My first question is what is the relationship between the two methods? I am using Storyboards so I think I should stick with the segues. But then how do I find out which employee object to pass?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Bryan

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        employee *dtlEmployee = [_employees objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        self.detailViewController.detailItem = dtlEmployee;
    }
    else
    {
//        employee *dtlEmployee;
//        
//        int row = indexPath.row;
//        int section = indexPath.section;
//        
//        NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
//        
//        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath animated:NO];
//        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath];
//
//        dtlEmployee = [_employees objectAtIndex:newIndexPath];

    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

        employee *dtlEmployee;

//        int row = [[self.tableView] indexPath.row];
//        int section = [self.tableView indexPath.section];
//        NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
//        dtlEmployee = [_employees objectAtIndex:newIndexPath];
//        NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
//        NSUInteger selectedRow = selectedRowIndexPath.row;
//        NSUInteger selectedSection = selectedRowIndexPath.section;
//        NSArray *tmpArray = [_employees objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];
//        dtlEmployee = [tmpArray objectAtIndex:selectedRowIndexPath.row];
//        dtlEmployee = [tmpArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//        
//       dtlEmployee = [_employees objectAtIndex:selectedRowIndexPath.]
//        
        if (isSearching)
        {
            dtlEmployee = [self.filteredEmployees objectAtIndex:self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];
        }
        else
        {
        dtlEmployee = [_employees objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
        }

        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:dtlEmployee];

    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
        //cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (isSearching)
    {employee *thisEmployee = [self.filteredEmployees objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = thisEmployee.fullName;}
    else
    {employee *thisEmployee = [[self.sections valueForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = thisEmployee.fullName;}

    return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Would you include your cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: Yes, I added it above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic for getting the right employee in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` looks like this:

```
if (isSearching)
{
    employee *thisEmployee = [self.filteredEmployees objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = thisEmployee.fullName;
}
else
{
    employee *thisEmployee = [[self.sections valueForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = thisEmployee.fullName;
}
```

But your logic in `prepareForSegue:sender:` looks like this:

```
if (isSearching)
{
    dtlEmployee = [self.filteredEmployees objectAtIndex:self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];
}
else
{
    dtlEmployee = [_employees objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
}
```

You need to make the logic when performing the segue match the one when populating the cell, which from the sound of it works correctly. It appears that you're doing it correctly when `isSearching` is true, so when it's not true, the following line should be used:

```
employee *thisEmployee = [[self.sections valueForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex: [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].section]] objectAtIndex: [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
```

Comment: That works great. I had used a convoluted method that took 6 lines of code.

Comment: //            UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)sender;
//            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
//            NSInteger totalRows = indexPath.row; //current section row value
//            //Find the row the employee is in by counting
//            for (int n = 0; n < indexPath.section; n++)
//            {totalRows += [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:n];}
//            dtlEmployee = [_employees objectAtIndex:totalRows];

Comment: But your method is more concise and logical. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your segue is connected to the table view cell, your sender in `prepareForSegue:` is actually a cell.  (Use logging or the debugger to be sure.)

That means you can ask your table view for an index path that matches the cell and use the same logic that you would have in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` for obtaining an object from a path.

Comment: I checked it is returning a table cell, so I am going to try to get it to work using the logic in tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath.